# Swapping fields in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a WinForms Project with a DataGridView, which is data-bound to a collection of objects.

One column contains the serial-number of a sensor, which the user can select from a list. If the user selects a serial-number which is already used in another item, I want so swap some (but not all) of the fields between the items.

This breaks the normal data-binding mechanism. Although the user has only edited one item, I will be actually be modifying two items.

What is the best way to handle this?

The easiest way appears to be to handle it in the CellValidating event. This definitely occurs before the data-bound item is updated (which is convenient in this case). Other possible events (CellEndEdit, CellValueChanged, CellValidated) occur later.

However, I don't like this, because CellValidating should be used for validation and not for other random stuff.

Alternatively, I could implement a mechanism for the item to call a function in its parent object and handle everything in the model, independent of the UI. That seems like a better structure (MVVM-like), but way more complicated.

Comment: I'd rather to handle it in the model rather than the UI.

Comment: At present, the items are in a simple collection, but they have no reference to the parent object and no reference to each other. Creating a view model would not change this basic problem. The view model for each item would require a reference to the container (or it could generate events to be handled in the container). I agree that this is a better structure, but it is more work (in this case probably too much).